# In Oracle, how do I make an external table that has the exact same structure as an existing table?

Tags: sql, oracle, external-tables

I know that you can create a table for export like this:

```
create table bulk_mbr organization external( 
type ORACLE_DATAPUMP
default directory jason_home 
location ('mbr.dat')) 
as SELECT * FROM mbr;
```

But I'd like to do something like this for imports so I can create an external import table with the same structure as an existing table, load data into it, and then do a simple INSERT INTO/SELECT FROM query to move the data over there.  Is there a way to do this?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
create table bulk_mbr organization external( 
type ORACLE_LOADER 
default directory jason_home 
location ('mbr.dat')) 
as SELECT * FROM mbr where 1=0;
```

But got:

> ORA-30657: operation not supported on
>   external organized table

Answer (score 2):

just use your table description:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE bulk_mbr (
  2     ID NUMBER,
  3     d VARCHAR2(4000)
  4  )
  5  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  6     TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  7     DEFAULT DIRECTORY jason_home
  8     LOCATION ('mbr.dat')
  9  );

Table created
```

Either from your DDL repository (you have one haven't you? :) or dynamically with `DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl` for example.

Comment: Yes, we do have one, but there are simply too many tables we're doing this with to manually make each table.  `DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl` is a good thought as well, but it doesn't seem like it will be easy to automate.  Is there another way to do this, or am I just going to have to bite the bullet and hack together a PL/SQL block to do all this from user_tab_cols?

Comment: This is probably not the answer the OP wants to hear - because it involves additional typing.  And it is frustrating that ORA-30657 kicks in with the ORACLE\_LOADER driver when it doesn't apply to the DATA\_PUMP driver.